# Custom ttk.Entry widget class focus problem, python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am trying to use a custom ttk.Entry class to make entering date form a little more easily. Two digits of int entering will add automatically current year and month. 4 digits ints entering will add automatically current year. 8 digits entring will automatically switch to date format. It is the main function I want. However when some wrong input, it could show some wrong massage and get focus of this Entry widget. I try `focus()` and `focuse_set()` but they don't work. Anyone has good solution for this problem? Thank you in advance.
Here are the codes accordingly

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime

class Date_entry(ttk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, master=None, textvariable = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master=master, textvariable = textvariable, **kwargs)

        self.bind('<Return>',   (lambda _: self.date_auto_fill(textvariable)))
        self.bind('<Tab>',      (lambda _: self.date_auto_fill(textvariable)))

    def date_auto_fill(self, args):
        try: 
            int(args.get())
            if len(args.get()) == 2:
                date_show = str(datetime.now().date().year) + '-' + str(datetime.now().date().month) + "-" + str(int(args.get()))
            elif len(args.get()) == 4:
                date_show = str(datetime.now().date().year) + '-' + str(int(args.get()[0:2])) + "-" + str(int(args.get()[2:4]))
            elif len(args.get()) == 8:
                date_show = str(int(args.get()[0:4])) + '-' + str(int(args.get()[4:6])) + "-" + str(int(args.get()[6:8]))
            else:
                date_show = "Wrong Format"
            try:
                datetime.strptime(date_show, "%Y-%m-%d")
                args.set(date_show)
            except ValueError:
                date_show = "Wrong Format"
                args.set(date_show) 
                self.focus()
        except:
            try:
                datetime.strptime(args.get(), "%Y-%m-%d")
            except:
                date_show = "Wrong Format"
                args.set(date_show)
                self.focus_set()

def main():

    def print_date(args):
        print(args)

    r=Tk()

    var1 = StringVar()
    var2 = StringVar()
    msg_var = StringVar()

    dateEntry1 = Date_entry(r, var1)
    dateEntry1.grid(row =0, column = 0)
    dateEntry2 = Date_entry(r, var2)
    dateEntry2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    b=ttk.Button(r, text="Print Date", command = lambda:print_date(var1.get()))
    b.grid(row=3)

    r.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Stovfl, yes, I checked the line    'self.focus_set()'    is reached absolutely. The wrong message is shown in the same Entry Widget.

Comment: While a event is processed a call of `self.focus()` will not be successful. Change to `self.after(0, self.focus`) a `return 'break'` may also be needed.

Comment: @stovfl you are right. it works. Thank you very much and have a good day